# Можно ли без пакета анаконда реализовать задачу ML

Tags: машинное-обучение, python-3.6, ibm

У нас есть стенд IBM Power AI,в котором нет пакета Anaconda, но есть Pytnon 3 и Jupyter. Есть ли возможность без библиотек реализовать задачу ML???

Comment: [IBM утверждает, что всё нужное есть](https://developer.ibm.com/linuxonpower/deep-learning-powerai/faq/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Библиотека - это просто кто-то вместо вас уже  потрудился и написал соответствующие программы. А Anaconda просто для вашего удобства собрала эти программы и дала возможность удобной их загрузки. Не хотите или не можете их использовать, считаете, что реализации в этих библиотеках неэффективны - никто не заставляет их использовать. Пишите свои.

Любую задачу ML можно реализовать на любом языке программирования - хоть Python, хоть C++, хоть Java, хоть R, Julia или Fortran. Вон, даже на JavaScript есть реализации. Но, естественно, для этого надо изучить - и весьма глубоко - соответствующие методы и алгоритмы ML, а также профессионально владеть соответствующим языком.

И еще: Jupyter - это среда разработки. Другими словами - особый тип IDE. И пользование ею -  никак не обязательный вариант организации работы разработчика или исследователя.